# Opendaylight neon: alternatives to old l2switch feature

Tags: opendaylight

During my search on stackoverflow, I already found out that l2switch is no longer supported in newer ODL releases.

I need its functionality for lldp topology creation, especially node and link overviews of the network.

The following REST command in ODL neon:

```
get /restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology
```

Just gives me nodes that I have added by hand (e.g. NETCONF connectors). So I think LLDP topology discovery it is not enabled by default. I did not find any similar features in:

```
feature:list
```

Is there any alternative to using an older release?

Answer (score 2):

there is no alternative built in to ODL that can do this for you, but you can
simulate it. l2switch pushes flows to the openflow switches to punt LLDP packets
to the controller in order to learn the links. I'm not sure if the network-topology
would get updated or not, but you could manually configure flows in your switches
to punt LLDP packets and check. You can configure flows via restconf, or just
manually create them however your switch is configured (e.g.,  ovs-ofctl add-flow
for openvswitch)